# Converting NSString to NSData without changing data

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, nsstring, nsdata

I have an NSString that contains a series of hex values, for example:

> 6173736e 616d65a2 15165570 6f696e74 584e534f 626a6563

However, I need this exact same data to be in an NSData object.  I have tried doing things such as:

> mydata = [mystring dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
>   //have tried all kind of encoding options

Regardless of what I do though, `mydata` never contains the same values the NSString had, which is what I need.

Would greatly appreciate any help! Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to misunderstand what that method does. It doesn't parse the string for hexadecimal representations of numbers; it just creates a data object that represents the string with a certain byte encoding. So in your case, the data will contain bytes with the values 54 (the ASCII value for '6'), 49 (for '1'), 55 (for '7'), 51 (for '3'),  55 (for '7'), 51 (for '3'), 54 (for '6'), 101 (for 'e') and so on.

If you want to parse hexadecimal strings, you can use NSScanner to scan for hex values.

Here's the basic form of what you want:

```
NSScanner *scanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:yourHexString];
NSMutableData *data = [NSMutableData data];
while (![scanner isAtEnd]) {
    unsigned value;
    if ([scanner scanHexInt:&value]) {
        [data appendBytes:&value length:sizeof(value)];
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Invalid value in scanned string");
    }
}
```

(Warning: Written in browser, haven't tested it, might cause a meltdown if you try to run a nuclear reactor with it, etc.)

Comment: I see.  So if I don't want to parse it, though, and merely want to create a data object with the exact same values as the String object, what's the best way to do that?

Comment: @none: Like I said, NSScanner. You have to parse it, because the string doesn't contain *values* — it's just a string of characters. *You* understand it as hexadecimal values because your brain is parsing it that you. You need to tell the computer to do the same, and NSScanner is how.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  Could you perhaps point me in the right direction? Haven't worked with an NSScanner before.

Comment: Thanks.  Unfortunately I tried it out and it says "Invalid value in scanned string" for each character

Answer (score 0):

**Taking the first character `6` as an example.**

The hex value for `6` the character (0x360d0a according to [this link](http://www.string-functions.com/string-hex.aspx), milage may vary depending on encoding) isn't the same as the hexvalue 0x6.

```
0x360d0a != 0x6
```

What you've got already appears to be data, though I'm not sure how you can write that data exactly again.

You may have to resort to something like:

```
-(NSData*) dataFromString:(NSString*) s
{
    NSMutableData *d = [[NSMutableData alloc] init] autorelease];
    for (int i = 0; i < [s length]; i++)
    { 
         char c = [s characterAtIndex:i];
         switch (c)
         {
             case '0': [d appendData:/*Add data to represent 0*/]; break;
             case '1': [d appendData:/*Is this append as simple as append:0x1*/]; break;
             ...
             case 'F': [d appendData:/*Add data to represent F*/]; break;
             //All 16 cases
         }
    }
    return d;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  The string is indeed originally from an NSData object.  It is now an NSString though; I want to convert it back to NSData. How would I do that exactly?

Comment: What does "saving that as NSData directly" mean? You think he actually has an NSData object that he's mistakenly assuming is an NSString?

Comment: I'm not sure what I meant! But have a look at the code example, I hope not, but you might have to resort to something like this.

Comment: Hmm, sorry I'm having a tough time here.  What would go in the `/*Add data to represent 0*/` area?

Comment: I think it's just `0x0`. Haven't tested though

Comment: Thanks.  What about the other cases though?  0x1,0x2...0x8? And then what?

Comment: there are only 16 hex characters. `0x0, 0x1, 0x2, 0x3, 0x4, 0x5, 0x6, 0x7, 0x8, 0x9, 0xA, 0xB, 0xC, 0xD, 0xE, 0xF`. Since the method parses characters one at a time, you don't need more than that.

Comment: On this line, for example: `case '1': [d appendData:0x1]; break;` it says: Incompatible integer to pointer conversion sending 'int' to parameter of type 'NSData *'

Comment: Sorry, not on a mac, so not got something I can test in front of me. I think it should be: `[d appendData:[NSData dataWithBytes:0x1 length:1]]`; Let me know if that works and I'll ammend

Answer (score 0):

Late to the party I know, but I recently had a similar problem, started with James Webster's answer and arrived at this:

```
-(NSData*) dataFromString:(NSString*) s
{
    NSMutableData *d = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
    for (int i = 0; i < [s length]; i++)
    {
        char c = [s characterAtIndex:i];
        [d appendBytes:&c length:1];
    }
    return d;
}
```