# copy NSString 's value in NSData's value without changing the contents of the value

Tags: objective-c, nsstring

I got a response from a server as `NSString` variable, and I need this value of `NSString` to decrypt it with 3DES, but must be `NSData`. I tried the conversion from `NSString` to `NSData`, but it doesn't work because it changed the content of the value. This is my code:

```
outputStream write:[encrypted bytes] maxLength:[encrypted length]];
uint8_t buffer[1024];
int len = [inputStream read:buffer maxLength:sizeof(buffer)];
myString = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:buffer length:len encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];

/* Here I get the response from server as NSString, and this exact value must be decrypted */

NSLog(@"response of the server in nsstring %@", mystring);
NSData *responseserv= [mystring dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

/* I convert it to NSData but the content of the value has changed*/

NSLog(@" response of the server in nsdata: %@", responseserv);

NSString *decrypted = [[self class] tripleDesDecryptData:responseserv key:@"Xm9d7@4Ru&2YaP&?14niO$f%" error:nil];
```

Comment: Show your download code (and please format the question text so it's more easily readable).

Comment: How does it change your value?

Comment: what encoding das the server even use

Comment: Why are you decoding the downloaded data using `NSASCIIStringEncoding` but turning the string into data using `NSUTF8StringEncoding`?

Comment: @Abizern, when i used it i got this value in my data:     31373623 39373443 35394137 43374433 43463833 46454339 46324431 36353744 33313837 31453932 41464230 44344230 44463833 36434639 35424142 45413337 46413836 35343146 36354642 33463934 31313131 43424438 32413746 35424630 37443338 41363846 39353042 36354136 33384343 43363131 37314130 38304132 33393745 42373242 46324444 32383536 42334641 46463533 36373946 32373444 31344639 43303033 44353132 43304631 42333330

Comment: Oh, well, now you've shown me the raw data I can instantly see what the problem is...

Comment: while the value of my string is :176#974C59A7C7D3CF83FEC9F2D1657D31871E92AFB0D4B0DF836CF95BABEA37FA86541F65FB3F941111CBD82A7F5BF07D38A68F950B65A638CCC61171A080A2397EB72BF2DD2856B3FAFF53679F274D14F9C003D512C0F1B330                                and i want keep this value in my nsdata

Answer (score 0):

Try to do this..

```
   NSString* str = @"teststring";
   NSData* data = [str dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

This is the way to convert NSString to NSData

Comment: thanx @praphin SP, but i already tried this code, and it didn't keep the content of the nsdata's value same  exactly as the nsstring's value, i hope that my question is more clear now

Comment: my problem is the same problem in this link, but it wasn't resolved: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7800793/converting-nsstring-to-nsdata-without-changing-data